# Java Multi-Threading Two instances of threads are the same thread object

Tags: java, multithreading

I am confused with the snippet from [this](http://osgi-in-action.googlecode.com/svn-history/r15/trunk/chapter04/dynamics/simple_tracker/src/org/foo/log/Activator.java) code:

```
void stopTestThread() {

    // thread should cooperatively shutdown on the next iteration, because field is now null
    Thread testThread = m_logTestThread;
    m_logTestThread = null;
    if (testThread != null) {
      testThread.interrupt();
      try {testThread.join();} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
  }
```

Does that mean testThread and m_logTestThread are different instances but point to the same object in the memory, so they are the same thread?

If so, what the purpose is of `if (testThread != null)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does that mean testThread and m_logTestThread are different instances
>   but point to the same object in the memory, so they are the same
>   thread?

This is partially true. Actually `testThread` and `m_logTestThread` are two different `references` not `instances`. And both the reference are pointing to the same `Thread` object. So, just making a `reference` `m_logTestThread` point to `null` does not make the `testThread` reference also point to `null`.

You can also see it in practice by a simple example: -

```
String str = "abc";
String strCopy = str;  // strCopy now points to "abc"
str = null;  // Nullify the `str` reference

System.out.println(strCopy.length()); // Will print 3, as strCopy still points to "abc"
```

So, even if you set one of the reference to null, the other reference still points to the same Thread object. An object is not eligible for Garbage Collection until it has `0 reference` pointing to it, or there is a `circular reference`.

See this link: - [Circular Reference - wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference) to know what exactly is `Circular Refeference`.

> what the purpose is of "if (testThread != null)" ?

Its simple. You can infer from the condition that, it is checking whether the `testThread` reference is pointing to a `null` object.
The `null check` is done so that, you don't get a `NPE` inside the `if-construct`, where you are trying to interrupt the Thread pointed to by that reference. So if that reference is pointing to `null`, then you don't have any thread associated with that reference to interrupt.

Comment: `An object is not eligible for Garbage Collection until it has 0 reference pointing to it.` does not account for circular references

Answer (score 0):

> Does that mean testThread and m_logTestThread are different instances but point to the same object in the memory, so they are the same thread?

`testThread` and  `m_logTestThread` are two references that point to same instance of `Thread` object. (say T)

```
Thread testThread = m_logTestThread;
```

This line means that `testThread` will start pointing to same object where `m_logTestThread` is pointing. i.e. both are pointing to T.

```
m_logTestThread = null;
```

This line means that `m_logTestThread` will start pointing to `null`, i.e. it's no more pointing to T. But, it doesn't change `testThread` and `testThread` is still pointing to T.

> what the purpose is of "if (testThread != null)" ?

because `testThread` may OR may not be `null`, hence this condition is used for further calculation before using `testThread`.